# Hash tables in prolog

Tags: data-structures, dictionary, hashtable, prolog

I was solving a puzzle in prolog the other day and realized that were I using another programming language, I would have made use of a hash table/dictionary, but as far as I know this isn't really possible in prolog.

So my first question is are there any prologs that support a dictionary-like data structure with the performance characteristics of a hash table?

Secondly, it occurred to me that since most prologs use a hash table to store predicates, I could write a wrapper predicate to assert and retract facts, creating a dictionary interface which would leverage the underlying hash table of predicates. But would I get the performance characteristics of a hash table, or would the the interface add overheads that would reduce the performance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found out that:

> SWI-Prolog version 7 introduces **dicts** as an abstract object with a
> concrete modern syntax and functional notation for accessing members
> and as well as access functions defined by the user.

The syntax is as follows:

`Tag{Key1:Value1, Key2:Value2, ...}`

See [Dicts: structures with named arguments](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=bidicts) for the details.

Note that :

- [These are first-class citizens of the language](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-dicts-motivation)
- Semantics of unification between dicts may change in the future
- The ./2 operator, formerly used for cons-ing, has been repurposed to access dict members via an expressions like `point{x:1,y:2}.x`
- [Dicts can be destructively modified](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-dict-assignment) but this is not recommended, being "non-logical", not to mention non-functional.
- [The current underlying implementation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-dicts-implementation)  is "a compound term using the functor `dict`. The first argument is the tag. The remaining arguments create an array of sorted key-value pairs"

The time-complexity of operations of the present (2019) implementation is given in the SWI Prolog manual under ["5.4.5: Implementation Notes about dicts"](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=bidicts#sec:5.4.5):

> Dicts are currently represented as a compound term using the functor
> `dict`. The first argument is the tag. The remaining arguments create
> an array of sorted key-value pairs. This representation is compact and
> guarantees good locality. Lookup is order *log( N )*, while adding
> values, deleting values and merging with other dicts has order *N*.
> The main disadvantage is that changing values in large dicts is
> costly, both in terms of memory and time.
>
> Future versions may share keys in a separate structure or use a binary
> trees to allow for cheaper updates. One of the issues is that the
> representation must either be kept cannonical or unification must be
> extended to compensate for alternate representations.

### And also

The SWI-Prolog dicts are built-ins and an SWI-Prolog extension. An alternative is [`library(assoc)`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=assoc), providing maps based on AVL trees via a library (thus available in other implementations, possibly).

Comment: I just saw that his had happened recently -- changing to be the accepted answer. We just had to wait a few years for it to be developed.

Comment: Do you happen to know the time complexity of dict computations, get and set? Are they O(logn) as in, say, ordered maps, or are they O(1) as (almost) in good, STL C++ hashtables, or something worse?

Comment: @Jason I added some time on the time complexity as given in the reference manual as of now.

Answer (score 8):

Some Prolog environments have *Association lists*, which can be used to create and edit a dictionary:

- [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=assoc)
- [SICStus Prolog](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dassoc.html#lib_002dassoc)

**Edit:**

You might be able to get better performance by implementing predicates in *foreign languages*, for example:

- SWI-Prolog [Java](http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/) or [C++](http://www.volker-wysk.de/swiprolog-c++/index.html)
- GNU Prolog [C interface](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog065.html)
- SICStus [C, C++](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Mixing-C-and-Prolog.html#Mixing-C-and-Prolog) and [Java/.Net](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Interfacing-_002eNET-and-Java.html#Interfacing-_002eNET-and-Java).

Comment: Ah cool, well that's certainly what I was after. Although it's worth pointing out that both those implementations have a lookup complexity of O(log(N)), so not quite the performance of a hash table.

Comment: Good point. I've edited my answer and added links to some Prolog interfaces to foreign languages.

Comment: Also check YAP Prolog, which is very efficient and has several data structures implemented (AVL trees, Splay trees, red-black trees etc): http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/

Comment: @Jay, SWI-Prolog uses AVL trees for `library(assoc)` aswell

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a Prolog guy (just an outside observer) but I found this:

http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.0.7/html/sicstus/lib_002davl.html

when I searched for "prolog finite map balanced trees". It says it's an alternative implementation of association lists.

(Why I thought of this: In Haskell, a purely functional language, instead of association lists or hash tables, it is common to use trees for (persistent) dictionaries or finite maps. Lookups are also O(log(N)). See [Data.Map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.2.0.1/doc/html/Data-Map.html) for some references on implementing maps with balanced trees.)

Answer (score 3):

The following comments address your question in an order going roughly from "more specific" to "more general".

First, addressing your concrete comment:

> I would have made use of a hash table/dictionary, but as far as I know this isn't really possible in Prolog.

All serious Prolog implementations allow you to destructively modify Prolog terms, using for example `setarg/3`. Using `arg/3` and `setarg/3` gives you O(1) access to each argument of a term, which is enough to implement a hash table exactly as in other languages, assuming your system does not place arbitrary limits on the arities of terms.

**It is not a good idea to do this yourself**, since you have to take into account unexpected copying and sharing of terms at all terms. Instead, rely on libraries to do it.

Which libraries? I second what others have written: Instead of hashing libraries, use **tree-based** libraries like `library(assoc)`, `library(avl)` etc. These are not quite as efficient as hashes in the average case, but:

- they are often efficient enough
- they scale very predictably: Most important operations are **always** in O(log(n)).

Also as others have written, destructive modifications are incompatible with logic programming, and the tree libraries have the huge advantage that they can be implemented in **ISO Prolog** and in a **pure way** with asymptotically **optimal efficiency**.

Finally, the dict extensions of SWI-Prolog are **not ISO conformant**, not even **syntactically**, and hence not portable to conformant Prolog systems! See Ulrich Neumerkel's [**comments**](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/SWI7_and_ISO) for how an infix dot can be added in an ISO-conformant way.

Answer (score 2):

In SICStus Prolog, use either the [assoc](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dassoc.html) or the [avl](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002davl.html) libraries.